# Does data transfer between google compute engine and persistent disks billable?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I understand that local-ssd disk does not incur any charges as it is located with the compute engine. Assuming the disk to be standard persistent disk, does the ingress and egress charges between the compute engine and disks billable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no network charges associated with Persistent Disk. You are [charged](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#persistentdisk) for the amount of *provisioned* space per disk (per GB, per month).

There *are* additional charges related to snapshots (for total snapshot size) and for network egress if you choose to restore a snapshot across regions.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, as it is stated in the Google Cloud Platform [website](https://cloud.google.com/virtual-network/).

Egress in between the same zone is free of charge, but any egress from a zone will be billed, depending from where to where you move the data. This includes any data movement from persistent disks or buckets.

Even if you have a subnet in between two zones in the same region, you will be charged for the egress.

Comment: If am not wrong, I think disks are zonal resources. We cannot provision a disk and a compute engine in two different zones. But for the bucket, it is possible and I understand that egress charges apply when the compute engine reads from a bucket which is in the different zone.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar Yes, disks are zonal resources and can only be accessed by other instances within the same zone. You cannot attach a disk to an instance in another zone (or another region). PD snapshots, however, are global.